# How to add Print Button to document document from Google doc viewer?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, google-api

I trying to display a Microsoft Word Document Google Doc Viewer, it has been working fine except there is no option to directly print document as a PDF file from the Viewer unless I click a pop-out icon then click on print.

I tried to add a html button style to absolutely appear on document viewer and script script to trigger printing iframe content, however it was cross origin issue (Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:5000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta https-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;" />
    <title>FlaskBlog</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #print {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 13px;
            left: 60%;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            border:0;
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="print">Print to PDF</button>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://legendaryapplication5.files.wordpress.com/2023/10/demo.docx&embedded=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            $('#print').on('click', function(e){
                document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.print()
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think there should be a workout that provided by google aip for printing since I not want click on serval step to print document as it is currently.

As far as I know, the Microsoft Office viewer provide this printing option as this

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://legendaryapplication5.files.wordpress.com/2023/10/demo.docx&embedded=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

However I prefer using Google Doc Viewer to Microsoft Viewer.
Please kindly help, thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution?